# How can i check if i am running in ring 0 / ring 3 on x64 CPU

Tags: kernel-mode, x86-64

I have read it is possible to check ring level with bit 3 of CS register.

Is there another register which really contains ring value (2 bits)

Comment: The Current Privilege Level can be found in bits 1 and 0 of CS.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this ?

```
0:002> dx (( ntdll!_KTHREAD *) @$thread)->PreviousMode
(( ntdll!_KTHREAD *) @$thread)->PreviousMode : 0 [Type: char]
0:002> ?? (( ntdll!_KTHREAD *) @$thread)->PreviousMode
char 0n0 ''
```

or in kmode

```
0: kd> dq gs:[188] l1
002b:00000000`00000188  ffff8889`d75ce080
0: kd> ? @$thread
Evaluate expression: -131349371625344 = ffff8889`d75ce080
0: kd> dx @$thread->Tcb.PreviousMode
@$thread->Tcb.PreviousMode : 1 [Type: char]
0: kd> uf nt!ExGetPreviousMode
nt!ExGetPreviousMode:
fffff804`41c45f00 65488b042588010000 mov   rax,qword ptr gs:[188h]
fffff804`41c45f09 0fb68032020000  movzx   eax,byte ptr [rax+232h]
fffff804`41c45f10 c3              ret
0: kd> ?? #FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_KTHREAD , PreviousMode)
long 0n562
0: kd> ? 0n562
Evaluate expression: 562 = 00000000`00000232
```

Comment: Yes, how do you print this information ? with qemu ?

Comment: not sure if I understand you if you wanted to know how I printed this --- it is with windbg --- if you are asking how to print it with Qemu by programming I don't know--- all I know is you can start a kernel debugging session attaching to a  Qemu instance with windbg